# How to Edit default URL in Restful web service

Tags: java, netbeans-7, restful-url

I created Restful web service using netbeans but I can't change the default URL. it is like this

```
http://localhost:8080/project/resources/path
```

so I need to change that url to

```
http://localhost:8080/project/search/path.
```

so is it possible to do that? please give a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the url in the service configuration